# NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined

Tags: python, datetime

I'm teaching myself Python and was just "exploring". Google says that datetime is a global variable but when I try to find todays date in the terminal I receive the NameError in the question title?

```
mynames-MacBook:pythonhard myname$ python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:37:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> date = datetime.date.today()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Where does it say that `datetime` is a global variable, exactly?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You need to import the module [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) first:

```
>>> import datetime
```

After that it works:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = datetime.date.today()
>>> date
datetime.date(2013, 11, 12)
```

Comment: This is not about common variables, this is about importing modules from the Python Standard Library: http://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html . You generally only import what you need, not everything.

Answer (score 6):

It can also be used as below:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime(2016,3,1)
end_date = datetime(2016,3,10)
```