# Cannot figure out this error in python 3Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'xlrd' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I have installed xlrd successfully, however, on attempting to use a command of xlrd:

```
xlrd.open_workbook('datafile.xls')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xlrd' is not defined
```

I cannot understand this error and how to rectify it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934248/nameerror-name-datetime-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Try

importing xlrd with:

```
from xlrd import *
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when I just used import xlrd